# PartNumber(s) Are Converting Into String While Multipart S3 API From Perl v5.36.0

Tags: amazon-web-services, perl, amazon-s3

I am trying to perform the aws S3 multipart api calls via my command line using perl scripting below is my relevant code snippet:

```
    my $part_no = 1;
    my %final_upload_file;
    my @multi_part_hash;
    
    foreach my $temp_file (@split_files) {
       my $tota_no_parts= @split_files;
       my $upload_part = "aws s3api upload-part --bucket <s3_bucket_name> --key ".$filename." --part-number ".$part_no." --body ".$temp_file." --upload-id ".$UploadId;
       $temp_json=`$upload_part`;
       
       my %upload_response = %{decode_json $temp_json};
    
       my $eTag = $upload_response{'ETag'};
       my %temp_part_hash;
       $temp_part_hash{'PartNumber'} = int($part_no);
       $temp_part_hash{'ETag'} = $eTag;
       push @multi_part_hash, \%temp_part_hash;
    
        if( $part_no le $tota_no_parts)
        {
         $part_no++;
        }
    }
my %final_hash;
$final_hash{'Parts'} = \@multi_part_hash;
print Dumper(\%final_hash);
```

So till this point data type of the values in the hash is correct only below is the o/p:

> $VAR1 = {
> 'Parts' => [
> {
> 'PartNumber' => 1,
> 'ETag' => '"46f438ba2afd8d6dc03958b867a349b1"'
> },
> {
> 'ETag' => '"7b1e03e9ed7bb49d907e5a2d25b89159"',
> 'PartNumber' => 2
> },
> {
> 'ETag' => '"30c23faad792c9b7c4b05356305cb6b0"',
> 'PartNumber' => 3
> },
> {
> 'ETag' => '"979174e5353386a75d8e36d223d22ea2"',
> 'PartNumber' => 4
> },
> {
> 'PartNumber' => 5,
> 'ETag' => '"ee93774d0a2ec9c27fae6a4fb3496804"'
> },
> {
> 'PartNumber' => 6,
> 'ETag' => '"9a2c5a1abe6869f370b07d76c270e569"'
> }
> ]
> };

Below is the further operation i am trying to in order to do the final complete-multipart-upload API call:

```
my $json_text = encode_json \%final_hash;
print("\$json_text: $json_text\n");
my $json_filename = 'test.json';
 open(FH, '>', $json_filename) or die $!;
 print FH $json_text;
 close(FH);
```

But if we see below o/p carefully seems like now all the values of part numbers are getting converted to string PSB:

> $json_text:
> {"Parts":[{"PartNumber":"1","ETag":""46f438ba2afd8d6dc03958b867a349b1""},{"ETag":""7b1e03e9ed7bb49d907e5a2d25b89159"","PartNumber":"2"},{"ETag":""30c23faad792c9b7c4b05356305cb6b0"","PartNumber":"3"},{"ETag":""979174e5353386a75d8e36d223d22ea2"","PartNumber":"4"},{"PartNumber":"5","ETag":""ee93774d0a2ec9c27fae6a4fb3496804""},{"PartNumber":"6","ETag":""9a2c5a1abe6869f370b07d76c270e569""}]}

So what could be the probable fix here that i can apply in order fix other-wise complete-multipart-upload api call is falling as it is expecting integer for partNumber instead of a String.

Error message:

> Parameter validation failed: Invalid type for parameter
> MultipartUpload.Parts[0].PartNumber, value: 1, type: <class 'str'>,
> valid types: <class 'int'> Invalid type for parameter
> MultipartUpload.Parts[1].PartNumber, value: 2, type: <class 'str'>,
> valid types: <class 'int'> Invalid type for parameter
> MultipartUpload.Parts[2].PartNumber, value: 3, type: <class 'str'>,
> valid types: <class 'int'> Invalid type for parameter
> MultipartUpload.Parts[3].PartNumber, value: 4, type: <class 'str'>,
> valid types: <class 'int'> Invalid type for parameter
> MultipartUpload.Parts[4].PartNumber, value: 5, type: <class 'str'>,
> valid types: <class 'int'> Invalid type for parameter
> MultipartUpload.Parts[5].PartNumber, value: 6, type: <class 'str'>,
> valid types: <class 'int'>

---

update

---

My use modules:

```
use strict;
use FileHandle;
use Getopt::Long;
use POSIX;
use Data::Dumper;
use feature q(say);
use JSON;
```

Comment: [Cpanel::JSON::XS::Type](https://perldoc.pl/Cpanel::JSON::XS::Type)

Comment: `if( $part_no le $tota_no_parts)` you want string comparison here?

Comment: @choroba I need numeric comparison only but i think with the context in perl it is working as comparison of numeric only; so are we expecting this is what it is causing the issue ?

Comment: My remark about string vs numeric comparison was unrelated to your problem. It might cause unexpected behaviour though.

Comment: @choroba i think in perl we don't have any thing specific data type like integer or float etc.. correct me if i am wrong ; it always goes with the context

Comment: @choroba sry my bad updated; but it will be helpful if you can give a fruitful solution here in order to fix this problem

Comment: You should post a [mre] demonstrating the problem. You don't show which JSON module you use.

Comment: @clamp i had added the imports; and i believe use JSON is the relevant one.

Answer (score 3):

That's why [Cpanel::JSON::XS::Type](https://perldoc.pl/Cpanel::JSON::XS::Type) exists.

```perl
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Cpanel::JSON::XS qw{ encode_json };
use Cpanel::JSON::XS::Type;

my $struct = {Parts => [{PartNumber => "1",
                         ETag => "46f438ba2afd8d6dc03958b867a349b1"},
                        {ETag => "7b1e03e9ed7bb49d907e5a2d25b89159",
                         PartNumber => "2"},
                        {ETag => "30c23faad792c9b7c4b05356305cb6b0",
                         PartNumber => "3"},
                        {ETag => "979174e5353386a75d8e36d223d22ea2",
                         PartNumber => "4"},
                        {PartNumber => "5",
                         ETag => "ee93774d0a2ec9c27fae6a4fb3496804"},
                        {PartNumber => "6",
                         ETag => "9a2c5a1abe6869f370b07d76c270e569"}
             ]};
print encode_json($struct,
                  {Parts => json_type_arrayof({
                      PartNumber => JSON_TYPE_INT,
                      ETag       => JSON_TYPE_STRING})});
```

Output:

```
{"Parts":[{"ETag":"46f438ba2afd8d6dc03958b867a349b1","PartNumber":1},{"ETag":"7b1e03e9ed7bb49d907e5a2d25b89159","PartNumber":2},{"ETag":"30c23faad792c9b7c4b05356305cb6b0","PartNumber":3},{"PartNumber":4,"ETag":"979174e5353386a75d8e36d223d22ea2"},{"PartNumber":5,"ETag":"ee93774d0a2ec9c27fae6a4fb3496804"},{"PartNumber":6,"ETag":"9a2c5a1abe6869f370b07d76c270e569"}]}
```

BTW: If you know something is a number, don't use string comparison on it.

Comment: We don't have Cpanel::JSON::XS this module and i thing type casting need these modules; so it will not work

Comment: it did not work for me with JSON module.

Comment: What prevents you from installing it?

Comment: Inside org Server will not allow mostly .

Comment: Show them why you need it.

Comment: Are we saying that this issue can't be resolved with any available JSON module provided by perl ?

Answer (score 2):

If you treat a number as a string, its internal representation will change. Try the following:

```
perl -MDevel::Peek -E'$a=99; say Dump $a; $b = "number: $a"; say Dump $a; say $b'
```

You will get

```
SV = IV(0x5592264fbed0) at 0x5592264fbee0
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (IOK,pIOK)
  IV = 99

SV = PVIV(0x5592264fe270) at 0x5592264fbee0
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (IOK,pIOK,pPOK)
  IV = 99
  PV = 0x5592264e7970 "99"\0
  CUR = 2
  LEN = 16

number: 99
```

If you use `sprintf` instead of the interpolation, it will remain the same:

```
$ perl -MDevel::Peek -E'$a=99; say Dump $a; $b = sprintf "number: %d", $a; say Dump $a; say $b'
SV = IV(0x56006d729e70) at 0x56006d729e80
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (IOK,pIOK)
  IV = 99

SV = IV(0x56006d729e70) at 0x56006d729e80
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (IOK,pIOK)
  IV = 99

number: 99
```

This means: Don't use `$part_no` in string comparison (as @choroba said), and build variable `$upload_part` with `sprintf`.

Comment: Ok first thing i corrected that instead of 'le' i am using '<' but i might miss the other resolution that we explained ; so what we have to do in order to have the key as integer instead of string in my final json file?